# Fetching multiple IDs in one request with React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

We have a GET API endpoint which given an array of IDs returns an array of objects matching those IDs.

We have a form where we need to lookup an arbitrary array of IDs using this API based on user selection.

We would like to use React Query to allow us to pass an array of IDs to it and it will return objects from the cache and/or fetch data, as needed.

One option we’ve considered is to have a custom hook which, given array of IDs, filters to those IDs in the cache and which should be fetched (by using what is returned from *getQueryData*). After fetch, iterate through response and *setQueryData* on each item. This feels a little convoluted and might not be leveraging React Query as much as it could.

Essentially our question is, how can we best use React Query when requesting multiple IDs in one GET request?

Comment: Ideally, you should be able to structure your app in such a way that you map each ID to a component, and then that component requests a single record by that ID. Failing that, you can use `useQueries()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ideally, we would like to lookup multiple IDs in one request as this is much quicker for the API we’re using than making those requests individually. Sounds like this might be going against what React Query provides out the box (given the one ID to one component concept) without building our own hook to manage it.

Comment: In that case yes, your API is a bit difficult to model with React Query. Your best bet will be to go the `setQueryData`/`getQueryData` route.

Comment: useQueries is the way if you want to fire separate requests. It sounds like you have an api that is capable of fetching data for multiple ids with one request? The question doesn't clearly specify that, but if so, have a look at batching: https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/365#discussioncomment-1867860

Comment: Thanks @TkDodo, that’s exactly what we’re after. Looks like we can borrow some of the concepts from that thread.